# How to change / add p tag style using DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, paragraph

I want a variable `font-size` in my `P` tag using the DOM but I can't seem to find a way to access it to change the styles. I tried this,

`document.body.p.style.font-size = ""+p_var+"px";`

along with trying several ways using `setAttribute` with no luck. Can anyone please show me how to change it if it is possible.

Comment: you want to set this through javascript? why dont you use `css` ?

Comment: Because CSS doesn't have variables I can change at runtime no?

Comment: 'p' is Not an object. but an array of objects. you need to iterate over the elements of this array.

Comment: Font size is applied through an element's style properties. These can be modified as properties of the element's style object, or through CSS, which can be modified by CSS rules set through a selector or class.

Comment: @am1r_5h—I don't see a jQuery tag on the OP. A collection of P elements can be created without using jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following code:

```
var s=document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for(i=0;i<s.length;i++)
{
    s[i].setAttribute("style","font-size:"+p_var+"px");
}
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kqfX/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this,

```
<p id="myP">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("myP").style.fontSize = ""+p_var+"px";
```

else if you want to set style for all the `<p>` tags try the below

```
var node; 
node = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = node.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    node[i].style.fontSize = ""+p_var+"px";
}
```

Also if you need to have same class name for `<p>` tags as below,

```
<p class="myP">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="myP">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

try this,

```
var node; 
node = document.getElementsByClassName('myP');
for (var i = node.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    node[i].style.fontSize = ""+p_var+"px";
}
```

Comment: But if I have more than one p-tag which is similar shouldn't I use `class = myP` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
Using jquery it can be done as

$("p").css({"font-size":"30px"});
```

Comment: Rob, edited. @Zword's answer is perfect for getElementsByTagName.

Answer (score 0):

First, prepair a css class for example

```
.font30 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Then do with jquery

```
$("p").addClass("font30");
```

It's good practice to work with class instead of inline css :)